# Database acl login design

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have 3 different types of users:

> -Client
>   -Employee
>   -Admin

And now i want only 1 login page to identify all of them.

My Example:
login table with fields:

> username password id clientid adminid employeeid role

client table with fields:

> name age address id.

And now I want add some client with username: admin. 
I can't add him because username like that exists (with role admin). Client table is only for extra info. The best solution should be 1 table with all info but what about fields i don't need. Example: I don't need field salary (should be nullable?) when i print client info, and let's say i have more than 50 fields only about employee info. I think my current database design is bad. What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches to think about.

One is to make a difference between a person and the roles she may take. This means a 1:1,n relation between person and role. All attributes describing the person, like name, user id, hashed password, go to the person, the role-specific attributes like salary go to the role. This is quite versatile if it really happens that one person takes several roles. I'm not sure about client and employee, but admin and employee sounds as if it could be taken by the same person.

If that's not the case, i.e. if each person is either client, employee, or admin, but never more than one of these, this would be overkill. Then you logically have an inheritance situation, where c, e, and a are special cases of person. There is more than one technique for implementing this in a relational database which doesn't support inheritance. The easiest is table-per-class-hierarchy, which really means putting all attributes of the general person and the specializations into one table and let them be null where necessary. In case of many attributes that are specific for each specialization, separate tables are also an option.

By the way, all this has nothing to do with whether you just want one login page for all of them. Even if you have more than one table, you can still define a view as a union of them, containing the user names and hashed passwords and possibly some more common data.

Also by the way, my remark in the first paragraph about the user credentials being a part of the person entity was a simplification. Being a user may also be a role that is not even necessarily bound to a person. Imagine some automatic job that needs to access your database. It is also a user that may be assigned certain privileges, but it's no person. I don't know whether your requirements make it wise to make this difference.